# What does "at the head of" mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I read a sentence in a [chapter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/lehs302.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwju8YuuwYTiAhVWinAKHTkCA30QFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1x1elGROXAK658lMUoDDMD) in my book which was:

> But now - now I march at the head of my retainers to Lucknow to try and drive you from the country.

I don't know what "at the head of" means here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"At the head of" means the speaker (Hanwant Singh) is the **leader** of his army.

In some cases the phrase can literally mean "at the front of", such as when someone marches or rides *at the head of* a parade. But the use in your example is more likely to be figurative.  Singh may not actually even be with his army *in person*, just with them *in spirit*, in that his leadership inspires them to achieve the goal of driving the British from his country.